# Restarting nginx: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I am unable to start my server. getting this error:

```
  Restarting nginx: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'passenger_root' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'passenger_root' directive, whichever is applicable. (-1: Unknown error)
```

Actually, my rvm list o/p is

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]
* ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

And for current app, I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.12. But my Passenger is taking ruby-2.0.0-p0 instead if ruby-1.9.3

Can anybody help me here. My server is down :-(

Comment: Any luck on this?  Same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Passenger takes what you set in the file nginx.conf by `passenger_ruby`, for example:

```
passenger_root /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.5;
passenger_ruby /home/dev/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby;
```